# Project 'ClassLibrary1.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-2.0

I have two class library project with the following setting:

- ClassLibrary1 --> Target framework-->.NET Core 2.1
- ClassLibrary2 --> Target framework-->.NET Framework 4.7.2

Now I referenced the ClassLibrary1 project in ClassLibrary2 project. It was done successfully. But on rebuilding the project I am getting an error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Project '..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.  ClassLibrary2

Can anyone help me to know the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you use `netstandard2.0` as a TargetFramework?

Comment: Use *.NET Standard 2.0* if you want to create a library project that can be referenced by both runtimes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target netcoreapp2.0 and net461 in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531784/how-to-target-netcoreapp2-0-and-net461-in-the-same-project)

Comment: I have following error with .Net Standard 2.0: Project ... is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project ... supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are not able to reference:

- .NET Core libraries from .NET Framework
- .NET Framework libraries from .NET Core

If you want to share code between those two libraries you have to use .NET Standard libraries.

.NET Standard is a kind of interface, a versioned list of APIs that you can call, .NET Framework and .NET Core implements this standard

Please see for reference:
[.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Comment: Thanks Szymom for the details. It helped me to understand the issue in details :).

Comment: Nice, clear, simple explanation. Thanks ;)

Comment: How do you use „.NET Standard libraries.“ — What parameter do I have to set?

Answer (score 2):

I changed my targeting class library to netstandard2.0 and it passed the builds.