# Project 'ClassLibrary1.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.1

I have some class library projects in targets `netstandard2.1`.

When I referenced that to my WPF project in target `.NET Framework v4.8`, On building time I get an error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Project '..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'.   WpfApp1

What can I do?

Update:
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083554/project-classlibrary1-csproj-targets-netcoreapp2-1-it-cannot-be-referenced) Q/A about referencing `netcoreapp2.1` and in that answer telling about add `netstandar2.1`. But my libraries are already in targets `netstandard2.1`!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What can I do?

1. If your library doesn't need the very latest features, use .net standard 2.0
   in general, a library should aim to support the lowest possible version.

or

2. port your WPF app to .NET Core 3 or later

Answer (score 20):

Here is the latest [compatibility documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) for .NET Standard versions.

.NET Framework will not support .NET Standard 2.1 or any other later version. For more details, see this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/).