# Calling class from another project

Tags: c#

I have two projects, `BasicCalculator` and `BasicCalculator.Test.Unit`. I am wanting to test classes with certain functions from the `BasicCalculator` project. I created a unit test file named `BasicCalculator.Test.Unit` and added a new reference (`BasicCalculator`) inside of that project.

```
using System;
using BasicCalculator;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace BasicCalculator.Test.Unit
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CalculatorEngineTest
    {
        private readonly CalculatorEngine _calculatorEngine = new CalculatorEngine();
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, whenever I type `private readonly CalculatorEngine _calculatorEngine = new CalculatorEngine();`
it displays an error for `CalculatorEngine` which is a class in the BasicCalculator project.

It says:

```
class BasicCalculator.CalculatorEngine

BasicCalculator - Available
BasicCalculator.Test.Unit - Not Available

You can use the navigation bar to switch context.

The type or namespace 'CalculatorEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Am not sure why this is occurring if I just needed to add a reference in the BasicCalculator.Test.Unit project that calls the BasicCalculator project.

**ADDED INFORMATION**

This is my class that I am trying to access inside of BasicCalculator.Test.Unit

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BasicCalculator
{
    public class CalculatorEngine
    {
        public double Calculate(string argOperation, double argFirstNumber, double argSecondNumber)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

[Solution Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPwd.jpg)

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMDer.jpg)

Comment: In both `BasicCaclualtor.Test.Unit - Not Available` and `CalcualtorEngine`, Calculator is spelled terribly wrong. This is pretty likely to be the source of your problem.

Comment: `CalcualtorEngine` != `CalculatorEngine`

Comment: I am sorry, I was re-typing the error message. But this is not the problem.

Comment: can you show us the basiccalculator.CalculatorEngine class? i suspect it may be the access modifier there

Comment: It's a different namespace, right? Don't you need `using BasicCalculator;` at the top of your test class file?

Comment: Please see updated post @Klaycon

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding the project as a reference doesn't expose the project's public members to all classes in your code. You need to tell the IDE you want to link the project and use its classes with a `using` statement:

```
using BasicCalculator;
```

Looking at the edited question, it seems `CalculatorEngine` has no access modifier, meaning it has protected visibility. Classes outside of the `BasicCalculator` project won't be able to access it. You'll also need to make it public:

```
public class CalculatorEngine
```

---

Edit: The error list in the updated question reveals an error:

> Project '..\BasicCalculator.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

This error is clearly stopping the `BasicCalculator` reference from resolving in your test project. You'll need to change the framework target in the project settings in one or the other so that they match. Or, research this error for other possible resolutions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083554/project-classlibrary1-csproj-targets-netcoreapp2-1-it-cannot-be-referenced) is a relevant SO question.

Comment: Doing this, still returns the same message.

Comment: According to the documentation if I am interpreting it correctly. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard) For BasicCalculator, I went to properties and changed the .net core to 2.0 and then rebuilt it (it was a success) then I changed the properties .net framework to 4.6.1 and rebuilt and and now I get the same error as above but this time for .netcoreapp2.0 and .NetFrameWork,Version=v4.6.1. Are these still not compatible? I looked at that chart on that link.

Comment: @simpleCoder I think you're misreading the table. The table specified which version the **.NET Standard** framework can act as a sort of interop between. Perhaps you have to make one of the projects target .NET Standard instead of .NETFramework or .NET Core.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I went ahead and created the first project as a .NETFramework and for the second one I used a .NETFramework and now I am able to use that class from the first project. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`class CalculatorEngine` should be `public class CalculatorEngine` to expose it to callers outside the project its declared in

you should also add `using BasicCalculator;` as @klaycon stated in his answer

Comment: I modified `class CalculatorEngine` to `public class CalculatorEngine` inside of the CalculatorEngine.cs file and then checked the `CalculatorEngineTest.cs` file and I still am getting the same message as before.

Comment: did you add the using statement per klaycons answer?

Comment: @simpleCoder make sure you recompile the project after changing the access modifier

Comment: Yes I did. @Muckeypuck

Comment: I did this as well. @Klaycon and still am getting the same message.

Comment: Youre sure you added the reference to BasicCalculator inside the test project?

Comment: @simpleCoder Does the line `using BasicCalculator;` error? If you write `BasicCalculator.` (with a dot) where the compiler would expect a type (class member, variable declaration) does IntelliSense bring up any class suggestions? Has the error message changed at all?

Comment: @Klaycon Please see my updated code (1st and 3rd block of code). That is how I have it set up. Even with your suggestions, I am getting the same errors.

Comment: @simpleCoder I know. I ask those questions because they are debugging steps that would help narrow down possible issues.

Comment: @Klaycon I added a picture of the errors I am getting.

Comment: BasicCalculator.test.unit wont build until BasicCalculator does. Whats test class?

Comment: @Muckeypuck BasicCalculator builds and runs perfectly until I add a new project (BasicCalculator.test.unit) within the BasicProject folder.

Comment: So I did the following: I removed the new project (BasicCalculator.Test.Unit) and created a new one. But this time instead of placing the new project inside of the BasicCalculator project, I placed it outside of the folder. And now when I added the reference and used `using BasicCalculator;` and build the new project. it returns this: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Project '..\BasicCalculator\BasicCalculator.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'. BasicCalculator.Test.Unit`